# How do I work with Qwt3D::Label?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, label, qwt

I want to know, how to use `Qwt3D::Label`, I mean, there are no any docs or examples in the Internet. I want to show my labels like plot title with fixed position. I analyzed qwtplot3d sources, how it shows title and wrote this code:

```
Qwt3D::Label m_Label;
m_Label.setString("Some text here");
m_Label.setRelPosition(Qwt3D::Tuple(0.7, 0.95), Qwt3D::TopCenter);
m_Label.draw();
```

But it always displays my label in different positions depends on scaling. So how to show label in fixed position of the screen?